# Keras loss converge to const

Tags: deep-learning, keras

I clearly don't understand something (first Keras toy)

My input x,y. X is 1D real values and y is a scalar
I want to predict if y is positive or negative. One way is to encode as one hot and use categorical_cross_entropy (which works) and the other is with a custome loss function that does the same (which doesn't work)
I'm training on a 8 examples and checking that I can overfit. My custom function gets stuck at 0.56

Here's the code:

```
import keras.backend as K

def custom_cross_entrophy(y_true, y_pred):
    '''expected return'''
    return -(K.log(y_pred[:,0])*K.cast(y_true<=0, dtype='float32') 
            + K.log(y_pred[:,1])*K.cast(y_true>0, dtype='float32'))

def build_model(x_dim, unites, loss_fuc):
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Dense(
        units=unites,
        activation='relu',
        input_shape=(x_dim,),
#         return_sequences=True
    ))
    model.add(Dense(
        units=2))
    model.add(Activation("softmax"))

    start = time.time()
    model.compile(loss=loss_fuc, optimizer="adam")
    print("Compilation Time : ", time.time() - start)
    return model
```

Now build and run model with custom

```
model = build_model(X_train.shape[1], 20, custom_cross_entrophy)
model.fit(X_train,y_train,
    batch_size=8,epochs=10000,
    validation_split=0.,verbose=0)
print model.evaluate(X_train, y_train, verbose=1)

#assert my custom_cross_entrophy is like catergorical_cross_entropy
pred = model.predict(X)
y_onehot = np.zeros((len(K.eval(y_true)),2))
for i in range(len(K.eval(y_true))):
    y_onehot[i,int(K.eval(y_true)[i]>0)]=1

print K.eval(custom_cross_entrophy(K.variable(y_train), K.variable(pred)))
print K.eval(categorical_crossentropy(K.variable(y_onehot), K.variable(pred)))
```

output:

('Compilation Time : ', 0.06212186813354492)
8/8 [==============================] - 0s 52ms/step
0.562335193157

[ 1.38629234  0.28766826  1.38613474  0.28766349  0.28740349  0.28795806
  0.28766707  0.28768104]

[ 1.38629234  0.28766826  1.38613474  0.28766349  0.28740349  0.28795806
  0.28766707  0.28768104]

now do the same with the Keras loss:

```
model = build_model(X_train.shape[1], 20, categorical_crossentropy)

model.fit(X_train,y_onehot,
    batch_size=8,epochs=10000,
    validation_split=0.,verbose=0)

print model.evaluate(X_train, y_onehot, verbose=1)
```

output:
('Compilation Time : ', 0.04332709312438965)
8/8 [==============================] - 0s 34ms/step
4.22694138251e-05

How is this possible? the losses should be the same mathematically
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, I'd say you're running two different evaluations:

```
print model.evaluate(X_train, y_train, verbose=1)
# ...
print model.evaluate(X_train, y, verbose=1)
```

but I don't know what's in y and y_train, so you might need to expand a bit more on what you're doing and how you're splitting the data. 
Try and run:

```
print model.evaluate(X_train, y_onehot, verbose=1)
```

to see if it was just a typo.

Cheers